# Sending a USB "keyboard" a set of output reports to switch USB modes

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, keyboard, usb

I have a camera that initial shows up as a USB keyboard and needs a sequence sent to it before it will reset the USB connection as a USB HID device.  This sequence is a set of output reports (1 Byte per report) setting and clearing "LED Status" flags.  Sometime the camera will attach as a USB HID device but still need the sequence.

My 2 Questions are:

1. How do I get Windows to send this "keyboard" the proper sequence?
2. How do I change the output report packet size (i.e. set it to 1 + reportID number instead of the 64 + reportID number that it is sending)?

Answer (score 0):

install *USBView* or *USB Device Tree Viewer* and post a screenshot or something. normally this can be done either by USB control requests ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539261(v=vs.85).aspx ) or USB HID feature reports ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/hid/introduction-to-hid-concepts ,   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539684 ) with no more information about the internal structure of the USB tree in the device this is impossible to say...

Comment: The Camera is a barcode/QR reader.  If it connects as a keyboard, Windows will not let me touch it via the HID API.  I will have to look at which feature byte to change for rare case it connects as a HID device, but thinks it is in keyboard mode.

Comment: barcode scanner appear as keyboards frequently see i.e. this http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/read-from-a-usb-barcode-scanner-that-simulates-a-keyboard-495358/ especially the lowest example. the key is to use the events the barcode scanner generates. whenever the scanner sends a HID report containing the scanned data it triggers an event. you can capture and process the event, you do not have to set the barcode sanner in another mode

Comment: for event handling in windows see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dacysss4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351713.aspx**

Comment: I need to get the barcode scanner out of keyboard mode to fully use it for what I need.  This requires me to send a sequence of output reports to it, but Windows reserves exclusive access to the device.  The sequence is setting and clearing the "led status lights".

Comment: normally only processes can get exclusive access. which process is it that grabs the bs ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: "Keyboard" and "Mice" are special HID classes that Windows takes exclusive control of. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/hid/keyboard-and-mouse-hid-client-drivers